# How to store Byte Array in DB2

Tags: database, db2

I have a table with column type as VARCHAR for BIT DATA. I want to store the String as byte array and want to read it back. Using the following code but not getting expected result.

```
    byte[] dbbytes = "Testing".getBytes("UTF-8");
    Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String updateSQL = "UPDATE TEMP SET col = '"+dbbytes+"'";
    stmt.executeUpdate(updateSQL);

    String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM REMOTE.temp";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
    while(rs.next()){
        byte[] s = rs.getBytes("col");
        String s1 = new String (s,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println("result is : "+s1);
    }
    conn.close();
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see an example of what you are getting back out.  Also perhaps what the data looks like in the DB.  You might try running in debug and examining the updateSQL variable.

Comment: What is the "expected result", and how that differs from what you think you get back? By the way, you should be using `PreparedStatement` and `setBytes()`/`getBytes()` instead of what you're doing right now.